# How to detect IE11 on Windows 10 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, windows-10, internet-explorer-11, jscript, browser-detection

- **it shouldn't depend on an easily spoofable method** <del>(e.g. user agent)</del>
- **it shouldn't be picked up by earlier versions of Windows**

AFAIK the only difference between IE11 on Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 is the removal of P3P.
Are there any other changes/unfixed bugs that could be used to detect it?
Something like the [IE11 on Windows 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/dev-guides/dn394063(v%3dvs.85)) guide—but for Windows 10—would be quite useful in that endeavour.

Comment: IE build number?

Comment: @KresimirPendic all builds compatible with Windows 10.

Comment: If it's not UA you can try some other `window.navigator` properties. Maybe some of them are more reliable.

Comment: Why would you ever need such a level of granularity for browser sniffing? In and of itself browser sniffing is unreliable and is not a common practice as it was abandoned years ago in favor of doing feature detection instead

Comment: @charlietfl we wouldn't have websites like http://browserhacks.com/ if that wasn't still a necessity. In my case I need to know if P3P is supported but that is irrelevant to my question.

Comment: Ok whatever, to my knowledge P3P is obsolete and was never widely adopted

Comment: @AndrewSvietlichnyy [`navigator` wasn't always read-only](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=364512). I can already detect IE11 reliably so maybe I could come up with something if it's read-only on IE11.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it:

```
if (
     // is IE 11 even in web workers
     !self.ActiveXObject && 'ActiveXObject' in self &&

     // exclude Windows 7/8/8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1
     /Windows NT 10.0/.test(self.navigator.userAgent)
   )
   console.log('IE11 on Windows 10');
```

I have also read that [HTTP/2 support is Windows 10 specific](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2014/10/08/http2-the-long-awaited-sequel/).